# Parents / siblings / children: struggling to select relevant element

Tags: jquery, parent-child, parent, siblings

I'm creating a blog and am trying to toggle an edit comments form using JQuery.

Here's the full code for the comments display section:

```
<!--================== COMMENTS DISPLAY SECTION     ====================================================================-->
<div id="comments">
    <% blog.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <div class="jumbotron comment">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="comment-ico" src = "<%=comment.author.image%>">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h4><%=comment.author.username%></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 date">
                 <%= comment.created.toDateString()%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div><p><%=comment.text%></p></div>

<!--=================EDIT COMMENT FORM =========================================================================-->
   <form class="edit-comment-form" action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments" method = "POST" id="newComment">
        <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" placeholder = "Type comment here..." name = "comment[text]"></textarea>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
<!--    ==================================================================================================================-->
<!--=================COMMENT OPTIONS (visible if user = author) =====================================================-->

    <% if(currentUser && currentUser.username == comment.author.username) { %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 choice">
                <a class="edit">Edit</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <form id = "delete-form" action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method = "POST">
                <input type = "submit" class = "button-delete" value = "Delete"></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
    <hr class = "style-three">
    <% }) %>
</div>
</div>
<!--====================================================================================================================-->
<!--======================ADD COMMENT FORM ================================================================================    -->
<% if(currentUser){ %>
<div class = "container form">
   <form action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments" method = "POST"  id="newComment">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="newComment-ico" src = "<%=currentUser.image%>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="comment">Add comment</label>
        </div>
    </div>
        <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" placeholder = "Type comment here..." name = "comment[text]"></textarea>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<% } %>
```

My JS is as follows:

```
$('#comments').on('click', '.edit', function(){
$(this).parents().siblings('.edit-comment-form').toggle();
})
```

However, this is selecting ALL dynamically displayed items (comments) so that when I click on the '.edit' element, all comments reveal their edit box. I know this is to do with how I am selecting them in terms of parent/sibling etc. but cannot work out what it should be!

Comment: You can just use `$('#comments').find('.edit-comment-form').toggle();`

Comment: thanks, but that is still selecting ALL of the comment forms produced dynamically. I need the toggle to only work on the specific comment I am clicking on

Comment: Try this once `$(this).closest('.row').prev('.edit-comment-form').toggle();`

Comment: That works great!!! Can you explain the logic on these as I've not used those selectors before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Satpal comment is perfect and credits to him, with his mercy though, I'll try to dive a bit deeper into the logics:

```
$('#comments').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').prev('.edit-comment-form').toggle();
});
```

Since `.edit` is ***inside*** of `.row` and `.edit-comment-form` ***before*** it (`.row`), basically you are impacting the ***previous*** `.edit-comment-form` of the closest `.row`'s clicked `.edit`.

On simpler words, the closest row is the same as the clicked edit and it's previous textarea (`.edit-comment-form`) will be toggled.

Here's a generic example of both **[prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** & **[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** jQuery methods:

- Also notes why `find()` didn't work, because it toggles all `.edit-comment-form` nested in `#comments`.

```js
var selected = $("#start");
selected.css("background", "gainsboro");

//prev() - Will select previous element disregarding tag name
$(".prev").on('click', function() {
  selected = selected.prev();
  $("div").css("background", "");
  $("nav").css("background", "");
  $("section").css("background", "");
  $("span").css("background", "")
  selected.css("background", "gainsboro");
});

//closest() - Will highlight red only if selected element is a div
$(".closest").on('click', function() {
  selected.closest('div').css("background", "red");
});

//find() - Will only highlight when span element is child 
$(".find").on('click', function() {
  selected.find('span').css("background", "red");
});

//Reset
$(".reset").on('click', function() {
  $("div").css("background", "");
  $("nav").css("background", "");
  $("section").css("background", "");
  $("span").css("background", "");
  selected = $("#start");
  selected.css("background", "gainsboro");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px lightgray solid;
  padding: 2px;
}

.inline {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
}

#row {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

section {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px lightgray solid;
  padding: 2px;
}

nav {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px lightgray solid;
  padding: 2px;
}

span {
  font-size: 14px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

button:hover {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="row">
  <div></div>
  <div class="find"></div>
  <span class="inline">span</span>
  <div><span>find() here</span></div>
  <section></section>
  <nav></nav>
  <div id="start"></div>
</section>
<button class="prev">test prev()</button>
<button class="closest">test closest()</button>
<button class="find">test find()</button>
<button class="reset">reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough answer. I do just have one issue now!! This toggle function is working perfectly on all comment items EXCEPT for the latest one to be added! When I click on the edit button for the last comment added, I just get redirected back to the top of the page.

Comment: In fact that's not entirely accurate. It won't work on any element that has just been added dynamically via the AJAX code. Once the page is refreshed it works fine though...

Comment: in fact scrap all of that!!! I hadn't inserted the form into my JQuery code within the AJAX function. Woops. Thanks a lot guys